# Why doesn't this Firefox bookmark keyword work?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I've defined a keyword bookmark in Firefox 3.6 (running on Windows Vista).

[image]

It's the same location as another one with a different keyword which works fine:

[image]

If I type `google test` it takes me to http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=test, but if I type `g test` it takes me to the first result from *I'm feeling lucky* as if there was no bookmark keyword there at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you don't have another bookmark with the same keyword, which would be taken before this one.

<strike>Or maybe it's simply reserved by Firefox for this keyword.</strike> *(according to comment, it's not reserved)*

Comment: It's not reserved, I use 'g' for google.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I ended up having a second bookmark for Google set to the keyword "g", only this one wasn't a search.  I removed the keyword and it works again.