# How can you set the default search provider in the adressbar for Firefox?

Tags: firefox, search

I'm trying to set the default address bar search engine to Duck Duck Go.

The expected functionality should work as such: I type something that is not an address in the address bar, the browser opens a Duck Duck Go results page for whatever I typed. Currently I am being given a Google results page.

I have already set:

```
keyword.URL = 'http://duckduckgo.com/?q='
keyword.enabled = 'true'
```

But this is not doing what I want.

I am *not* talking about the search box (which can have a dropdown to choose different providers, shown [here](https://superuser.com/questions/233925/how-do-i-get-firefox-to-use-bing-as-the-default-search-provider)) I am talking about the address bar (which is used to navigate to URLs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that setting was removed by Mozilla. The alternative way is to set the search bar engine to DuckDuckGo and the address bar will also work as needed.

In order to change the search engine, navigate to Firefox preferences, click on the `Search` tab, find `Default Search Engine`, drop-down the list which might currently be set to Google, and select DuckDuckGo.

[image: Photo of settings]

Comment: Ok, how do I set the search bar when I don't use it?

Comment: In order to change the search engine, navigate to Firefox preferences, click on the 'Search' tab, find 'Default Search Engine', drop-down the list which might currently be set to Google, and select DuckDuckGo.

[Photo of settings](http://media.askvg.com/articles/images5/Disable_Firefox_Search_Suggestions_One_Click_Buttons.png)

Comment: I just tested this with Firefox 35.0 and I can confirm that the address bar search mirrors the currently selected search engine in the search bar.

Comment: Ah, it's nice to see they've made it easier to set. @Sarge Please add your steps into your answer and it will be complete.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. I have edited my original answer with the steps.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this page and add it to firefox

https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/search-engines/

This page is automatically opened in firefox using menu options/search/other search engines

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bookmark keywords](https://superuser.com/questions/134769/why-doesnt-this-firefox-bookmark-keyword-work) to search from the address bar with them (like **wr** for the Russian Wikipedia etc.).

However, to change the default search with no keywords to a custom URL, you need to create a "search plugin". You can do so by [following this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Creating_OpenSearch_plugins_for_Firefox) or using [this site that does it automatically for you](http://www.searchplugins.net/generate.aspx). After you create a new plugin, you can set it as your default search engine from the **about:preferences#search** options page.